# How to 2-way bind localStorageService in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I am right now building a customer-cashier type of app using browser's local storage. I figured how to use local storage but it is not updating cashier side if I give a new order from customer side.

```
app.controller('posController', function($scope,localStorageService,Data,$rootScope,$window){
  console.log(localStorageService.get("placedOrder"));
  $scope.orders = localStorageService.get("placedOrder");
});

app.controller("orderController",function($scope,Data,localStorageService){
  var arr = localStorageService.get("placedOrder") || [];
  arr.push({"name":$scope.name,
                        "order": $scope.order,
                         "time": Data.time,
                         "email": Data.email
                       });
  localStorageService.get("placedOrder",arr)
  console.log(Data.placedOrder);
});
```

so the posController should get updated as soon ordercontroller updates the localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the cashier and customer are using different systems this will not work. Local Storage is for the browser and not meant for these types of transactions. You will need to use a database thats hosted on a network for this type of application.

Comment: I think i understand you, but i got this question from interview and it says use localstorage of your browser or use firebase .. I am not familiar with firebase .. So i thought to use this .. moreover when i refresh i am able to get hold of the updatedlocalstorage ..

Comment: So assuming the cashier and customer are using the same browser... you first need to initialize your orders in the storage. So create an empty array by doing something like localStorageService.set('placedOrder', []); Right now you never actually write to the storage because you just create an empty array instead of using the localStorageService.

Answer (score 0):

You need to communicate to other controller, that something is changed, please update your data.

That is possible by using 
event communication, it allows you to decouple your logic.

You have to call/ fire event like this

`$rootScope.$brodcast("myevent");`

And other side you have to use like below for listening fired event.

`$rootScope.$on("myevent",function(){
....Update your other controller data...
});`

Comment: Hey can you please expand your answer, i saw something like this but was not able to produce results, still would like to see your answer (: , thanks!

Comment: I tried to answer,but mobile stackoverflow site not allowing me put non-formated code & on mobile site not possible to format. I will answer your question tomorrow only from machine. I hope meanwhile you will find way.